# Help me not kill my tree

Tags: trees, tree-care

Or is it too late? My thumbs are decidedly not green.

I went to the local nursery and bought a tree and potting soil for a pot on my deck. Local means central utah.

I didn’t have a pot to transfer to yet so I put it in the garden with a drip line that watered every other day. Enough water was going in when it watered that it would come out the bottom.

It started drying out.

We transferred it to the new pot and it has continued drying out. Now the top half (was like a balding grandpa when we transferred) is dead.

We’ve been watering it every couple of days keeping the soil moist like the label said.

Have I killed the tree? Is there something I’m missing? What should I do?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a gonner ... major sunburn. I'd bring the plant and receipt back and ask for credit for a different tree. Maybe they have a 90-day guarantee. A topiary needs frequent shaping, not for the beginner and not low maintenance.

Comment: Poor little guy looks stressed out.  Personally, I would not give up on it yet.  I can't quite tell from the picture if you already have, but if not adding some mulch to the pot would help keep it from drying out.  Is the dead area still expanding?  Is it only on the side that gets the most sun?

Comment: Yes, the area is still expanding. The tips of green on the bottom is starting to go now too. 

There is some mulch on the dirt, yes. 

Even if it is too late, what should I have done differently?

Comment: @Gidgidonihah I'm not sure, there's a lot that can go wrong to stress a plant.  I would suggest talking to the nursery you bought it from and asking them for advice.  I've also learned a lot joining community garden and tree planting groups near me, maybe there's a group like that near you?